# XSLT combining 2 nodes into a new node

Tags: xml, xslt

Im struggling with XML and XSLt transformations, i have the following.

```html
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<playlist>
  <song>
    <title>Little Fluffy Clouds</title>
    <artist>the Orb</artist>
  </song>
</playlist>
```

I want to combine  title and artits into a new node called: info

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <!--Identity Transform.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title | artits">
        <info>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </info>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above returns:

```html
<playlist>
  <info>Little Fluffy Clouds</info>
  <info>the Orb</info>
</playlist>
```

I need to combine these, this is supposed to be simple but i cant get it right, what i would want is:

```
<playlist>
  <info>Little Fluffy Clouds the Orb</info>
</playlist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template for `song` and use apply-templates for its children's text nodes like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<!--Identity Transform.-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="song">
    <xsl:copy>
        <info>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title/text()"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="artist/text()"/>
        </info>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can also use, alternatively:

```
<info>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(title,' ',artist)"/>
</info>
```

Comment: +1 for nice code, one small clarification, xsl:copy required at 'song'?